# Create intranet site to manage vlans

Tags: asp.net, access-point, vlan

I work with a retirement home that has many apartments in one building. The goal is for each apartment to have the semblance of a home network(printer, computer chromecast). The problem is we have a bridge in each apartment that takes our wifi internet, then broadcasts another wifi for that apartment. So in the same building we have wifi for apartment 101-130 and 201-230 and 301-330. So we are over saturated with wifi signals.

My plan is to create a wpa2 enterprise network, give each appartment a login that will send them to a different vlan. Have another network for devices that can't auth with an enterprise network. this new network would b called "devices" which they can connect their chromecasts or rokus to. The network "devices" would be a separate vlan. Then on their computer they would hit a intranet site and possibly see a list of devices attached to "devices" network. then they could select their device and it would transfer to their vlan and leave the list. Ideally the list would empty every 10 min or so making it likely that the only devices on the "devices" network is the one I am trying to connect.

So after explaining my problem my question is this
A: is there a better-easier way to do this while keeping in mind that they are mostly old people.
B: is there a way to create a website that is able to change a device's vlan, and if so what language or platform would it be.

I have already done the first part using Meraki aps and Network Policy Server as Radius. I just don't know what to use to create the web page.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work the way you want. The chomecast connects to the devices network, but then signed-in laptop can't find it because they are on different vlans and the resident still gets mad .

As to option for a web site to manage vlans, that will depend greatly on the vendor(s) used in your network... but mainly the RADIUS or accounting system. *Any* web platform can be made to accomplish this: asp.net, node, php, etc. They can all do it. But all of them will require a significant amount of code to be designed and written. *Nothing* is gonna make this easy for you out of the box.

One option in some wifi systems (namely Ruckus and AeroHive) allow you to create multiple pre-shared keys for a single SSID network name, so the network appears more like the "normal" secured home network residents should already be familiar with. This is called Private Pre-Shared Key, or PPSA, and it is possible for each pre-shared key to map devices using that key to a different vlan network.

Then you can give a key to each resident apartment. A wider array of devices will work on the core network. You only need to further get involved when residents leave (you don't want prior residents having keys to a new resident's vlan) or lose their key.

Comment: For the first paragraph, the plan is to switch to vlan of the chromecast to that of the resident. Kinda like a 2 step connection process.
I do like your idea of Ruckus or AeroHive, I'll look into it. Thanks